# firebase hosting multiple sites configure .firebaserc file

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have firebase hosting working successfully in my project however I want to use the same database for a different site on a subdomain so I thought I would click add another site on firebase hosting.

I can configure the a records etc for the domain with no issues but am having trouble deploying content to the secondary site.

For example if I run `firebase init` and follow the prompts my `.firebaserc` looks the same in both my main project and my sub project.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "<project-name-here>"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the file which hosting site you are trying to deploy to? I have seen references to multiple databases [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding) but I don't think this is relevant to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set deployment targets:

```
firebase target:apply hosting target-name resource-name
```

Where the parameters are:

- `target-name` — a unique identifier (that you've defined yourself) for the Hosting site that you're deploying to
- `resource-name` — the name of the Hosting site as listed in your Firebase project

---

Let me know if it works!

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites

Comment: @Frank after reading the documentation and other posts I still feel there is no depth in any of the explanations. for eg. what is <target-name> & <resource-name>? is target name the name I give when I click on _Add Site_ ? And is resource name the name I give when I click on _Add App_ ? Do I have to edit my firebase.json with an array of **target** & **public** for every WebApp that is tied to this Firebase project?

Comment: If you're having a hard time making this work, post a new question with the [minimal-but-complete steps that reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What's the difference between "Hosting site that you're deploying to" and "the name of the Hosting site as listed"?

Comment: Target-name is just something you make up when you run this command - an alias to call the site by. i.e. staging or prod.

Resource-name is the site name (not project id). You can see your available sites on the hosting tab of firebase: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<my-project-name>/hosting/main

Answer (score 0):

It's this one:

[image]

It's a text name you entered like `my-firebase-app`, not a generated string of characters.

And make sure you are logged in to `firebase` with the correct account, you'll obviously get issues if your not but could think they are a problem with the id. Maybe even run `firebase logout`, `firebase login`.